# R iterate to create list of lists/vectors without appending

Tags: r

**Edit**
I think I solved it with Map()

```
mylist <- Map(list, colors = colors, items = items)
names(mylist) <- codes
```

---

Forgive my lack of experience here and apologies if I fudge some terminology. Correction and guidance appreciated.

I want to create a list of vectors so I may access each element using the $ operator.

If I create something like this:

```r
mylist <- list()
mylist$r1$color <- 'red'
mylist$r1$items <- c('red1','red2','red3')
```

Then the correct structure is created and I am able to access `mylist$r1`, `mylist$r1$items`, `mylist$r1$items[2]`, etc.

```r
List of 1
 $ r1:List of 2
  ..$ color: chr "red"
  ..$ items: chr [1:3] "red1" "red2" "red3"
```

However, I have multiple lists and so need to avoid hard coding and so would like to iterate to create a list of multiple elements all with the same structure though perhaps different length sub-elements. Something like:

```
codes <- c('r1','b1','g1')
colours <- c('red','blue','green')
items<- list(c('red1','red2','red3'),c('blu1','blu2','blu3', 'blu4'),c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

Given this data, I would like to iterate to create a structure like this:

```r
List of 3
 $ r1:List of 2
  ..$ color: chr "red"
  ..$ items: chr [1:3] "red1" "red2" "red3"

 $ b1:List of 2
  ..$ color: chr "blue"
  ..$ items: chr [1:4] "blu1" "blu2" "blu3" "blu4"

 $ g1:List of 2
  ..$ color: chr "green"
  ..$ items: int[1:8] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Enabling me to call, for example:

```r
> mylist$b1
$color
[1] "blue"
$items
[1] "blue1" "blue2" "blue3" "blue4"

> mylist$g1$items[3]
[1] 3
```

I have attempted to construct multiple for loops but can't seem to separate the lists into the correct structure within `mylist`. The `codes`, `colors` and `items` lists just get appended as is.

I'd appreciate some pointers in achieving my aims please.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to create a list from corresponding elements of `colours` and 'items', then set the names of the output list with `codes`

```
mylist2 <- setNames(Map(list, color = colours, items=items), codes)
```

-checking

```
> str(mylist2)
List of 3
 $ r1:List of 2
  ..$ color: chr "red"
  ..$ items: chr [1:3] "red1" "red2" "red3"
 $ b1:List of 2
  ..$ color: chr "blue"
  ..$ items: chr [1:4] "blu1" "blu2" "blu3" "blu4"
 $ g1:List of 2
  ..$ color: chr "green"
  ..$ items: num [1:8] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: I think you posted your reply at exactly the same time I posted my edit! I figured out Map(), but didn't realise about setNames. Thank you!

Comment: @r0bt sometimes the page refreshes a bit slowly.  So, I didn't see your edit while I posted the solution